# Как обработать нажатие на эту назад при открытой клавиатуре?

Tags: java, android

Как обработать нажатие на кнопку назад при открытой программной клавиатуре? Есть ли у этой кнопки слушатель? Или хотя бы как она называется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот нашел [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Хех, хоть что-то, буду смотреть, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь это тебе поможет

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
//If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
if (view == null) {
    view = new View(activity);
}
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);}
```

словить это событиие можно так:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Этот код скрывает клавиатуру, а ему нужно перехватить нажатие на кнопку back при открытой клавиатуре.

Comment: Нельзя так словить это событие. Это событие можно было бы словить, если бы не была включена программная клавиатура. И вообще при использовании onKeyUp или onKeyDown нет никакого отклика при нажатии на эту кнопку